# Vuex abstract common methods for inheritance (Large SPA)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Large SPA Vuex question - is there a way to abstract common methods that can be inherited or injected into Vuex namespace modules? What I have below works, but feels kludgy as I have to standardize states, etc. I could pass in assoc. array keys to accommodate different state stores, but looking to streamline. Ive look at Vuex plugins and I think there is way to use that to some degree, but again not ideal if I wanted something as simple as `getById()`

Another approach is to create a `Vue IoC factory container, Vue provider, with a Vuex driver, services for for common components`, but that is a lot of overhead and I feel would be an overkill, but maybe that is the best approach for a large SPA. Would appreciate some guidance as to where this is the right approach.

**vuex-common.js**

Collection of common service methods. I could create a common for getters, mutations, actions, etc.

```
import isArray from 'lodash/isArray'

export function getById () {
    return state => {
        const find = val => state.data.find(x => x.id === val)
        return val => isArray(val) ? val.map(find) : find(val)
    }
}
```

**Namespace store example -- store/modules/Users.js**

```
// removed other imports for brevity sake

import { getById } from 'vuex-common'
import forEach from 'lodash/forEach'
import {fetchUsers} from '~/api/apis/users.api';

const initialState = () => ({
    data: []
});

const state = initialState();

const getters = {
    getById: getById() // vuex-common
    // removed other getters for brevity sake
}

const actions = {
    async getUsers({commit, getters}) {
        try {
            const {data} = await fetchUsers();

            forEach(data, (u) => {
                /* Import getById vuex-common function */
                if (!getters.getById(u.id)) { 
                    commit('ADD_USER', u);
                }
            });

        } catch (e) {
            console.error("ERROR", e.message, e.name);
        }
    },
}

// removed mutations and exports for brevity sake
```